# Previewing PDF files using FuelPHP

Tags: php, pdf, fuelphp

I am trying to display PDF files that were uploaded in FuelPHP using the `<object>` and `<embed>` tags.

Note: If you go to the page, /upload/image?image_id=1 downloads the correct pdf. But when it is embedded in my browser, it is not visible. I'm using the latest version of Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116

Another note is that if the pdf is in the htdocs folder, the preview also shows fine. Also, I use this method of downloading to show images as well, which work fine with an `<img src="/upload/image?image_id=some_num">`

Here is my Rest Controller..

```
<?php
class Controller_Upload extends Controller_Rest
{

    public function after($response) {
        parent::after($response);       
        return $this->response(json_encode($this->data));
    }

    public function get_image()
    {
        $image_id = Input::post("image_id");
        $file_name = (Input::get('image_name') != null) ? Input::get('image_name') : Model_Db_Storage::get_image($this->userid, $image_id);

        if($file_name)
        {
            $this->response->set_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
            File::download(APPPATH.'/tmp/'.$file_name);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['image'] = $file_name;
            $this->data['response'] = 'Error Receipt not Found';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<object data="/upload/image?image_id=1" type="application/pdf">
    <embed src="/upload/image?image_id=1" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like an HTML question rather than an actual FuelPHP question because you said that it worked when viewing the PDF directly in your browser.

I think that you would be better off using an iframe tag.

See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185774/embed-pdf-file-in-html-using-object-tag).

Look at [Mozilla's docs on iFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Simple example would be:

```
<iframe width="400" height="215" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="/upload/image?image_id=some_num"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with by deciding to output raw bytes instead.

I changed the HTMl code to an iframe instead

```
<iframe src="/upload/image?image_id=1"></iframe>
```

Then I changed the way that I output the file:

```
$this->response->set_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
//File::download(APPPATH.'/tmp/'.$file_name);
echo File::read(APPPATH.'/tmp/'.$file_name);
return new Response();
```